# How to create custom eval metric for catboost?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, catboost

Similar SO questions:

- [Python Catboost: Multiclass F1 score custom metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354410/python-catboost-multiclass-f1-score-custom-metric)

Catboost tutorials

- https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples.html#user-defined-loss-function

## Question

In this question, I have a binary classification problem. After modelling we get the test model predictions `y_pred` and we already have true test labels `y_true`.

I would like to get the custom evaluation metric defined by following equation:

```
profit = 400 * truePositive - 200*fasleNegative - 100*falsePositive
```

Also, since higher profit is better I would like to maximize the function instead of minimize it.

How to get this eval_metric in catboost?

## Using sklearn

```py
def get_profit(y_true, y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred).ravel()
    loss = 400*tp - 200*fn - 100*fp
    return loss

scoring = sklearn.metrics.make_scorer(get_profit, greater_is_better=True)
```

## Using catboost

```py
class ProfitMetric(object):
    def get_final_error(self, error, weight):
        return error / (weight + 1e-38)

    def is_max_optimal(self):
        return True

    def evaluate(self, approxes, target, weight):
        assert len(approxes) == 1
        assert len(target) == len(approxes[0])

        approx = approxes[0]

        error_sum = 0.0
        weight_sum = 0.0

        ** I don't know here**

        return error_sum, weight_sum
```

## Question

How to complete the custom eval metric in catboost?

## UPDATE

My update so far

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import sklearn

from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def get_profit(y_true, y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred).ravel()
    profit = 400*tp - 200*fn - 100*fp
    return profit


class ProfitMetric:
    def is_max_optimal(self):
        return True # greater is better

    def evaluate(self, approxes, target, weight):
        assert len(approxes) == 1
        assert len(target) == len(approxes[0])

        approx = approxes[0]

        y_pred = np.rint(approx)
        y_true = np.array(target).astype(int)

        output_weight = 1 # weight is not used

        score = get_profit(y_true, y_pred)
 
        return score, output_weight

    def get_final_error(self, error, weight):
        return error


df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
X = df[['survived','pclass','age','sibsp','fare']]
y = X.pop('survived')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=100)


model = CatBoostClassifier(metric_period=50,
  n_estimators=200,
  eval_metric=ProfitMetric()
)

model.fit(X, y, eval_set=(X_test, y_test)) # this fails
```

Comment: You linked custom loss, which is used for training, and eval metric, which is used for evaluation only and doesn't affect training. Which one you are interested in?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov The original dataset is about customer churn and I have defined custom metric which calculates "profit" based on TP,TN,FP,FN of binary classification. I would like to directly optimize that metric "profit" instead of "auc", how is it possible in catboost?

Comment: Eval metric will not affect training. If you want your training to optimize (maximize) your custom metric you need to (1) write a gradient and hess for your function to optimize or (2) find a readily available one that closely replicate yours

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Ok, I got that. Then, I would only like to get the eval metric with the default loss function. Still, my eval_metric is not working. If you guide through example, I would greatly appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference from yours is:

```
@staticmethod
def get_profit(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = expit(y_pred).astype(int)
    y_true = y_true.astype(int)
    #print("ACCURACY:",(y_pred==y_true).mean())
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    loss = 400*tp - 200*fn - 100*fp
    return loss
```

It's not obvious from the [example](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples.html#user-defined-loss-function) you linked what are the predictions, but after inspecting it turns out `catboost` treats predictions internally as *raw* log-odds (hat tip @Ben). So, to properly use `confusion_matrix` you need to make it sure both `y_true` and `y_pred` are integer class labels. This is done via:

```
y_pred = scipy.special.expit(y_pred) 
y_true = y_true.astype(int)
```

So the full working code is:

```
import seaborn as sns
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from scipy.special import expit

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
X = df[['survived','pclass','age','sibsp','fare']]
y = X.pop('survived')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=100)

class ProfitMetric:
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_profit(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = expit(y_pred).astype(int)
        y_true = y_true.astype(int)
        #print("ACCURACY:",(y_pred==y_true).mean())
        tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
        loss = 400*tp - 200*fn - 100*fp
        return loss
    
    def is_max_optimal(self):
        return True # greater is better

    def evaluate(self, approxes, target, weight):            
        assert len(approxes) == 1
        assert len(target) == len(approxes[0])
        y_true = np.array(target).astype(int)
        approx = approxes[0]
        score = self.get_profit(y_true, approx)
        return score, 1

    def get_final_error(self, error, weight):
        return error

model = CatBoostClassifier(metric_period=50,
  n_estimators=200,
  eval_metric=ProfitMetric()
)

model.fit(X, y, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: This runs perfect. I did `print(model.get_evals_result())` this gives gives me the profit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why loop when you already have the confusion matrix?

Comment: If we do list unpacking, it does not work (`tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred).ravel() does not work`). Only the for-loop works.

Comment: @BenReiniger There is a problem in catboost inner working, for some loop instead of `[549   0 342   0]` it returns `[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  16  90 287 126  30   0   0   5  82 110 129  16   0   0   0   0   0   0]` meaning it's not a binary classifier anymore. This is why unpacking fails.

Comment: You might need to check that this is working as intended: is the `np.rint` always producing 0 or 1?  The Accuracy example in OP's link takes an argmax, and the Logloss example seems to suggest that `approxes` is the log-odds output.

Answer (score 1):

By way of example, I implemented a very simple metric.

It counts the number of times y_pred != y_true in a multi-class classifier.

```
class CountErrors:
    '''Count of wrong predictions'''
    
    def is_max_optimal(self):
        False

    def evaluate(self, approxes, target, weight):  
        
        y_pred = np.array(approxes).argmax(0)
        y_true = np.array(target)
                                    
        return sum(y_pred!=y_true), 1

    def get_final_error(self, error, weight):
        return error
```

You can see it used if you run this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class CountErrors:
    '''Count number of wrong predictions'''
    
    def is_max_optimal(self):
        False # Lower is better

    def evaluate(self, approxes, target, weight):  
        
        y_pred = np.array(approxes).argmax(0)
        y_true = np.array(target)
                                    
        return sum(y_pred!=y_true), 1

    def get_final_error(self, error, weight):
        return error
    

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkleinbort/resource-datasets/master/abalone/abalone.csv')
y = df['sex']
X = df.drop(columns=['sex'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=12)

model = CatBoostClassifier(metric_period=50, n_estimators=200, eval_metric=CountErrors())

model.fit(X, y, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
```

Hope you can adapt this to your use-case.

Comment: This is great and works, but I am looking for a way to get custom score for binary classification.

Comment: This should work with a binary classification.  Try replacing this line: `return sum(y_pred!=y_true), 1` with your custom metric